# No header of 1st column of php generated table

Tags: php, html-table

I got a function from a different site to generate a table based on a PHP query:

```
function SQLResultTable($Query)
{
    $host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "Quality_Monitoring";
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());      //build MySQL Link
    mysql_select_db($db) or die('Could not select database');        //select database
    $Table = "";  //initialize table variable

    $Table.= "<table id='Table1' border='1' style=\"border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center; font-size: 10px; cellspacing: 5px; \">"; //Open HTML Table

    $Result = mysql_query($Query); //Execute the query
    if(mysql_error())
    {
        $Table.= "<tr><td>MySQL ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "</td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        //Header Row with Field Names
        $NumFields = mysql_num_fields($Result);
        $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF;\">";
        for ($i=0; $i < $NumFields; $i++)
        {     
            $Table.= "<th>" . mysql_field_name($Result, $i) . "</th>"; 
        }
        $Table.= "</tr>";

        //Loop thru results
        $RowCt = 0; //Row Counter
        while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
        {
            //Alternate colors for rows
            if($RowCt++ % 2 == 0) $Style = "background-color: #CCCCCC;";
            else $Style = "background-color: #FFFFFF;";

            $Table.= "<tr style=\"$Style\">";
            //Loop thru each field
            foreach($Row as $field => $value)
            {
                $Table.= "<td>$value</td>";
            }
            $Table.= "</tr>";
        }
       // $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; color: #FFFFFF;\"><td colspan='$NumFields'>Query Returned " . mysql_num_rows($Result) . " records</td></tr>";
    }
    $Table.= "</table>";

    return $Table;

}
```

What I need to do is not have a header for the first column, but keep the column there, with the records in it.  can anyone help me out how to do this? Total noob when it comes to PHP and don't really know where/what I'm looking to amend.  Any help appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Truth allready said it, Please use some standard and well tested framworks/libraries.  They might have been tested by many on different conditions and environments.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this section of code:

```
    //Header Row with Field Names
    $NumFields = mysql_num_fields($Result);
    $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF;\">";
    for ($i=0; $i < $NumFields; $i++)
    {     
        $Table.= "<th>" . mysql_field_name($Result, $i) . "</th>"; 
    }
    $Table.= "</tr>";
```

So your function will be:

```
function SQLResultTable($Query)
{
    $host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "Quality_Monitoring";
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());      //build MySQL Link
    mysql_select_db($db) or die('Could not select database');        //select database
    $Table = "";  //initialize table variable

    $Table.= "<table id='Table1' border='1' style=\"border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center; font-size: 10px; cellspacing: 5px; \">"; //Open HTML Table

    $Result = mysql_query($Query); //Execute the query
    if(mysql_error())
    {
    $Table.= "<tr><td>MySQL ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "</td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
    //Loop thru results
    $RowCt = 0; //Row Counter
    while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
    {
        //Alternate colors for rows
        if($RowCt++ % 2 == 0) $Style = "background-color: #CCCCCC;";
        else $Style = "background-color: #FFFFFF;";

        $Table.= "<tr style=\"$Style\">";
        //Loop thru each field
        foreach($Row as $field => $value)
        {
            $Table.= "<td>$value</td>";
        }
        $Table.= "</tr>";
    }
       // $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; color: #FFFFFF;\"><td colspan='$NumFields'>Query Returned " . mysql_num_rows($Result) . " records</td></tr>";
    }
    $Table.= "</table>";

    return $Table;

}
```

But on that note, this function uses `mysql_*` functions which are rather old and (thesedays) nasty. You might want to consider moving to [PDO](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Edit: Try this:

```
function SQLResultTable($Query)
{
    $host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "Quality_Monitoring";
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());      //build MySQL Link
    mysql_select_db($db) or die('Could not select database');        //select database
    $Table = "";  //initialize table variable

    $Table.= "<table id='Table1' border='1' style=\"border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center; font-size: 10px; cellspacing: 5px; \">"; //Open HTML Table

    $Result = mysql_query($Query); //Execute the query
    if(mysql_error())
    {
        $Table.= "<tr><td>MySQL ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "</td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        //Header Row with Field Names
        $NumFields = mysql_num_fields($Result);
        $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF;\">";
        for ($i=0; $i < $NumFields; $i++)
        {     
            $Table.= "<th>" . mysql_field_name($Result, $i) . "</th>"; 
        }
        $Table.= "</tr>";

        //Loop thru results
        $RowCt = 0; //Row Counter
        while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
        {
            //Alternate colors for rows
            if($RowCt!=0)
        {
            if($RowCt % 2 == 0) $Style = "background-color: #CCCCCC;";
            else $Style = "background-color: #FFFFFF;";

            $Table.= "<tr style=\"$Style\">";
            //Loop thru each field
            foreach($Row as $field => $value)
            {
                $Table.= "<td>$value</td>";
            }
            $Table.= "</tr>";
        }
    $RowCt++;
        }
       // $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; color: #FFFFFF;\"><td colspan='$NumFields'>Query Returned " . mysql_num_rows($Result) . " records</td></tr>";
    }
    $Table.= "</table>";

    return $Table;

}
```

Comment: Ah sorry didn't explain myself very well, I do need the Header row, just need the first column header to be blank.

Comment: @ChrisSpalton I am not sure I understand, What do you want displayed in the header rows?

Comment: just need the first Column, ('Column A'if you like) to have no value in the header row, columns B, C, D etc, need the header in there as normal.

Comment: Nope sorry mate, that just limits the table to the Header Row plus 1 row of data.  Also keeps the Column header in.

Comment: @ChrisSpalton Dammit, they stuck the `++;` inside an if statement. updated the edit.

Comment: //Header Row with Field Names
        $NumFields = mysql_num_fields($Result);
        $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF;\">";
        for ($i=0; $i < $NumFields; $i++)
        {   
  if($i==0){  
            $Table.= "<th>" . "</th>";}
   else {
   $Table.= "<th>" . mysql_field_name($Result, $i) . "</th>";
   }
    
        }
        $Table.= "</tr>";

Comment: @ChrisSpalton Do you want to update my answer with working code, so the next chap that comes along gets the answer mate?